# Linear programming partition problem

Tags: linear-programming, set-partition

I have a list positive integer. My goal is to partition all the integers into two subsets such that the sum of the subsets are as close as possible. There are no constraints.

I immediately thought of this as a partition problem, and approximation algorithms, but I am supposed to solve this using linear programming.

Can I solve this using linear programming, if yes, can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

$x_{ij}=1$ if and only if integer $n_i$ is put in set $j\in \{1,2\}$.

You want to minimize 
$$
\left| \sum_{i}n_{i}x_{i1} - \sum_{i}n_{i}x_{i2} \right|
$$
subject to
$$
x_{i1} + x_{i2} = 1\quad \forall n_i
$$
(each integer is in set $1$ or $2$, exclusively)

Comment: If I am to solve this in excel, or matlab, they require the objective function to be constant. E.g. 2x_1 - x_2. I'm not sure I completely understand the objective function.

Comment: Indeed, you need to linearize it. Do you know how to ?

Comment: No, I do not. Is it hard? Can you help? I have matlab at my disposal, they probably have some tools I can use, but I still need to understand how to apply it in linear programming.

Comment: you can linearize $Z=|f(x)|$ as follows: replace the objective function by $Z = z$ and add the constraints $\pm f(x)\le z$

Comment: If I have m intergers, does that mean I would have $$\left| n_{i1}x + n_{i2}x + .... + n_{i_{m}}x - n_{i1}x - n_{i2}x - .... - n_{i_{m}} \right|$$

and I would have to make $m$ constraints each  $$\ n_{i}x - n_{i}x \le z $$

Comment: Sorry. Last was supposed to be $$\left| n_{1}x + n_{2}x + ... + n_{m}x - n_{1}x - n_{2}x - ... - n_{m}x \right|$$